# MySQL upgrade from 5.7.12 to 8.0.26 performance impact

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, workbench

On same system upgrade from MySQL 5.7.12 to 8.0.26 performance is going down, is there any specific config parameter that i need to change to get the same performance as 5.7.12.

Connection string for 5.7.12:
server=localhost;user id = root; password=xxxx;persistsecurityinfo=True;database={0};Sslmode=none;defaultcommandtimeout=300;connectiontimeout=10;maxpoolsize=150

Connection string for 8.0.26:
server=localhost;user id = root; password=xxxx;persistsecurityinfo=True;database={0};defaultcommandtimeout=300;connectiontimeout=10;maxpoolsize=150

i need to insert huge data into database for that 5.7.12 takes 12 hours but 8.0.26 is taking 26 hours to insert same data.

Config parameters for both:

1. slow-query-log=0
2. innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
3. innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
4. innodb_log_file_size=512M
5. max_allowed_packet=16M

Computer configuration:
16GB RAM
4CPU
1TB hard disk

Example:

```
INSERT IGNORE
    INTO  activity_info (file_id, lineIndex, isoTimestamp, zzzz,
                nodeType, action, errorCode,xxx, yyyy, data )
    VALUES  ('1759769327','1434','2018-05-26 01:25:13','110',
                'TBM','ADD','','','206763',''),
            ('1759769327','1436','2018-05-26 01:25:13',
                '17','TBM','DIVERTED','0000','','205678',''),
            ('1759769327', '1438','2018-05-26 01:25:13','121',
                'TBM','ADD','','','208543',''),
            ...;
```

Comment: What does the Insert look like (single-row? batched? LOAD DATA? mysqldump?)  What are/were values of sync_binlog?  If possible grab `SHOW VARIABLES` from each version and diff them.  You will find some defaults have changed.

Comment: its bulk insert, i mean multiple rows together and i compared all the variables are same on both hardware. Sync_binlog = 1.

Comment: Hmmm...  Can you show us a simple bulk insert plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE INTO activity_info (`file_id`, `lineIndex`, `isoTimestamp`, `zzzz`,  `nodeType`, `action`, `errorCode`,`xxx`, `yyyy`, `data`) VALUES ('1759769327','1434','2018-05-26 01:25:13','110','TBM','ADD','','','206763',''),('1759769327','1436','2018-05-26 01:25:13','17','TBM','DIVERTED','0000','','205678',''),('1759769327','1438','2018-05-26 01:25:13','121','TBM','ADD','','','208543','') .......

Comment: Hmmm...  That looks good.  I can't think of anything between the versions based on that query.  How about the Create Table.  Also, how many rows being inserted at one time?  Is the `IGNORE` likely to hit dups?  What are the settings of `net_buffer_length`, `max_allowed_packet`, `bulk_insert_buffer_size`.